# Column formatting from R to Excel (with package=xlsx), when you do not know column indices ahead of time (is there a better way)?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I've been toying around with the xlsx package as a way of exporting output from R, and I'm having problems setting column data formats when you do not know (beforehand) what columns will be formatted which way.

As an aside, I found this most fantastic post on tradeblotter a huge help in getting me to this point.  I highly recommend it: [background post from Tradeblotter blog](http://tradeblotter.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/writing-from-r-to-excel-with-xlsx/)

In my use case, I'm generating reports monthly, and each month the data.frame to be exported will increment by 1 or more columns (that then need to be formatted correctly).  I do not want to manually go in and set column names in the code, but would rather have R count the number of columns for me, then feed a vector of indices to the xlsx code.

After studying the structure of the colStyle list objects, I was able to create this workaround, but I have to believe that there is a better way, and I'm looking for some help in finding it.

Thanks in advance!
Chris

```
require(xlsx)
iris$cost <- rbinom(nrow(iris), 3, .85)+1000
iris$cost2 <- rbinom(nrow(iris), 3, .85)+1000
test <- createWorkbook()
# Define some cell styles within that workbook
csSheetTitle <- CellStyle(test) + Font(test, heightInPoints=18, isBold=TRUE)
csdollar <- CellStyle(test, dataFormat=DataFormat("$###,##0.00")) # ... for ratio results
csdefault <- CellStyle(test, dataFormat=DataFormat("0.00")) # ... for ratio results
csTableColNames <- CellStyle(test) + Font(test, isBold=TRUE) + Alignment(wrapText=TRUE, h="ALIGN_CENTER") + Border(color="black", position=c("TOP", "BOTTOM"), pen=c("BORDER_THIN", "BORDER_THICK"))
csTableColNames <- CellStyle(test) + Font(test, isBold=TRUE) + Alignment(wrapText=TRUE, h="ALIGN_CENTER") + Border(color="black", position=c("TOP", "BOTTOM"), pen=c("BORDER_THIN", "BORDER_THICK"))
sheet <- createSheet(test, sheetName = names(ytddflist)[i])
rows <- createRow(sheet,rowIndex=1)
sheetTitle <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1)
setCellValue(sheetTitle[[1,1]], "iris data with cost ($)")
setCellStyle(sheetTitle[[1,1]], csSheetTitle)

default.format = list(
  '1'=csdefault,
  '2'=csdefault,
  '3'=csdefault,
  '4'=csdefault)
dollar.format =list(
  'notused'=csdollar)

# here is where I create the dollar.format list object that will eventuall be fed to addDataFrame
dollar.format.list <- rep(dollar.format, 2)
names(dollar.format.list) <- as.character(c(6, 7))

addDataFrame(iris, sheet, startRow=3, startColumn=1, colStyle=c(default.format,dollar.format.list), colnamesStyle = csTableColNames)

saveWorkbook(test , "iriswithdollarx2.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you still need it, but I spent some time "fighting" with the `xlsx` package, in order to produce Excel files from R containing a lot of tables, without knowing in advance the number of the columns, so here's my strategy.

The key point is the creation of the colStyle list; instead of

```
default.format = list(
  '1'=csdefault,
  '2'=csdefault,
  '3'=csdefault,
  '4'=csdefault)
```

a shortcut is to create the list as a vector of `list` objects, and then assign the names to its elements:

```
default.format <-  rep(list(csdefault), 4) # style for the first 4 columns
dollar.format <- rep(list(csdollar), (dim(iris)[2]-length(default.format))) # style for remaining columns
format <- c(default.format, dollar.format) # create the colStyle list
names(format) <- seq(1, dim(iris)[2], by = 1) # assign names to list elements

# add dataframe to the workbook
addDataFrame(iris, sheet, startRow=3, startColumn=1, colStyle=format, colnamesStyle = csTableColNames)
```

Comment: This helped a lot! My code ended up looking like this: TABLE_CELL_STYLE <- CellStyle( wb ) +
            Font( wb, name = 'Consolas', heightInPoints = 12  ) +
            Alignment( wrapText = TRUE, vertical = "VERTICAL_CENTER" );
    TABLE_CELL_STYLES <- rep( list( TABLE_CELL_STYLE ), ncol(geneData) );
    names( TABLE_CELL_STYLES ) <- 1:ncol(geneData);